# Facebook Like not showing right image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I am using php and display rows of thumbs and records stored in mysql db.

I also have a Like button where the user clicks on it and it will come out in the user's facebook wall.

Text and links are appearing correctly but the thumbnail is always the one from the first record.

How can I make facebook show the correct thumb in the facebook wall?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
echo '<li>'; 
echo '<div class="thumb"><a href="inner.php?id='.$db_field['id'].'&title='.$db_field['title'].'&views='.$db_field['views'].'"><img src="images/thumbnails/'.$db_field['image'].'" alt="" /></a></div>';

echo '<div class="text_lvl_1">'.$db_field['title'].'</div>';

echo '<div class="facebook_buttons">';
echo '<fb:like href="http://www.mydomain.com/inner.php?id='.$db_field['id'].'" send="true" align="middle" layout="button_count" width="135px" show_faces="false"></fb:like>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</li>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a separate page for each image? On each page, show in the open graph tags, the image for that page.

If you have multiple images for one page, there's no way for the like to pick a different one each time. It's because the open graph tags are rendered before the JS (so if you use JS to manipulate, you can't.)

You can test this with the Facebook linter tool.

Comment: The functionality you probably want is what FB is calling "open graph actions," which you can do programmatically in PHP, but isn't the like button. That's for per-page-liking.

Answer (score 1):

So your `inner.php?id=123` is actually the page showing the individual images? Have you placed any code inside these pages telling facebook what the image address is, like a link element with `rel="image_src"` or an Open Graph meta element?

Comment: Ref: So your inner.php?id=123 is actually the page showing the individual images? - Yes, that's correct. As for your second question...the answer is no ... how would I do that?

Comment: <link rel="image_src" href="path/to/image.png" /> – or for the OG version, see documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Do I add this code to the page that contains the like button? and if yes ... I have a problem as there are lots of different like buttons..each added to their own image. So how I'm I going to assign that value without knowing which like the user clicked? Do I add it to the loop code? I'm a bit confused

Comment: You add it to the page you want to be liked, of course … so if inner.php?id=123 shows the picture with id #123, then in that page you refer to picture #123. And if inner.php?id=124 shows picture #124, then … well, you should be able to figure that out by yourself :-)

Comment: That's what I thought so I added this to inner.php ... <link rel="image_src" href="images/thumbnails/<?php echo $url_thumb; ?>" /> I then tested it and it still shows the wrong image

Comment: Put one of your test pages through the FB debugger -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug